# Christmas Cracker

Tags: riddle

Found this riddle in a Christmas cracker and after a few drinks it took me far too long to complete than it should have:

> What goes on and on and has 'I' in the middle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to this riddle is

> Onion (ON I ON)

Answer (score 3):

The last time I heard this joke, the answer was

> an onion
>  Explanation: "on and on with i in the middle" = ON + I + ON = ONION

Comment: Downvoting because he was 8 seconds slower?  Harsh.  Welcome to PSE, Mike, we're not all that hasty :)

Comment: @Rubio the downvote came just before I corrected the formatting so was probably for that. Still +1, shame you just missed out